# DateTimePicker in MVC using JQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, datetimepicker

In my mvc application, I need a datetimepicker. I got a code for this from [Here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples).

So first i refer these js and css files.

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then,

```
<div>
@Html.TextBox("fromdate", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"), new { @class = "from-date-picker", @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>
```

and in the script,

```
$('.from-date-picker').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
            timeInput: true,
            stepHour: 1,
            stepMinute: 5                
        });
```

So I got a datetime picker like this.

[image: datetimepicker with slider]

But here time is selecting by using a slider. I am trying to make it like the following type.

[image: timeselection without slider]

So tried like this.

```
$('.from-date-picker').datetimepicker({
    controlType: 'select',
    oneLine: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
```

But still its coming like the old style. That is with slider. How can I change to the second type?

Comment: Could it be that you don't add `css` files for this kind of layout?

Comment: @teovankot : I have added jquery-ui.css.

Comment: I've checked on github. src include [this css file](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/blob/master/src/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css) for timepicker. Have you add it?

Comment: @teovankot : Thanks. Just now i added "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" to my project. But the issue remains same.

Comment: Have you clear browser cache?

Comment: And do yo have any errors in console?

Comment: @teovankot : No errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100737/discussion-between-bko-and-teo-van-kot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create jsfiddle with [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/u04tdwa8/1/).

Everything works like charm.

I suppose you just don't add some js or CSS. Here is what I add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great it worked but when I press 'Now' button it shows me correct time first time but when I click on it twice or more, it set 07-Jul-2023 03:00 am. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below link

[code.runnable.com](http://code.runnable.com/UgCgGBRfEwILAAEt/how-to-create-date-time-picker-using-jquery-ui)

```
 $(function() {
    $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker({

        controlType : 'select',
        /*
         * timeFormat Default: "HH:mm", A Localization Setting - String of
         * format tokens to be replaced with the time.
         */
        timeFormat : "hh:mm tt",

    });
});
```

This code working properly here.

Comment: Yah. But I am using the same code in my application along with the same js and css files. But Its not working properly in my application. Don't know what i am missing....

Answer (score 1):

Finally Its working fine now. Working code is,

```
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
    
<div>
    <input type="text" value="" id="from-date-picker" />
</div>  

    <script>
        $('#from-date-picker').datetimepicker({
                    controlType: 'select',
                    oneLine: true,
                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
                });
    </script>
```

And, it is giving the output like,

[image: datetimepicker]

Thanks to all.

Comment: Great! it worked but when I press 'Now' button first time, it shows me correct time but when I click on it twice or more, it set 07-Jul-2023 03:00 am. Any Idea?